# run a function on client JS at interval update from server

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

so my question is this.

I have a simple ajax javascript that reads and parses a simple json file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var idn=5;
var someval = "this is my var";
var url2 = "update.php";

function jsonparse(arr) {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = arr['t'];

} //end function

function get_json(url,id) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            jsonparse(arr);
        } //end if
    } //end function

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url2, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",  "application/x-www-form-  urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("a="+idn+"&b="+someval);
} //end function

function init() {
    setInterval(function () {
        get_json(url2,0);
    }, 1000 * 5); //update every 5 secs
} //end function

</script>
```

So as you can see I have a set interval that updates every 5 seconds, and triggers the jsonparse function, of course this is an oversimplified example but it illustrates my question.

The question is can I have something happen in PHP that will trigger the get_json function on the client side, every 5 seconds.

In other words rather than having the client make the request have the server send the data to the client and when that happens the client will update its div in this case?

I would rather not have to use jquery if possible.

Comment: In short, no. - PHP doesn't maintain a connection to a client. You want the client side (JS) to handle that.

Comment: What is wrong with the javascript interval? Seems like that accomplishes the same thing. Short of that, you'd need to use sockets. You can look at Ratchet possibly if you REALLY think it needs to happen this way: http://socketo.me/

Comment: That isn't to say it's not possible. But realistically, you would be putting a lot of time and effort into creating something that JS is already meant to do. You will also find that there will be a ton of complications. Such as figuring out if the client has left the page or the fact that instead of getting the client to do it for free you are now paying for the server resources to do it.

Comment: at Nick J, I think the reason I would want the server to do the updates is because the clients are not trusted to use the proper time intervals. What is to prevent a client from opening console and using there own set interval function at say 10ms instead of the 5000 i set it to. Now they have created a poor mans DOS attack as it were. or someone alternatively could set a function that updates every 60000ms , so now the info on the client side is not being updated accurately.

Comment: Well there's nothing you can do to prevent that. Technically any browser is capable of that whether you create an update function or not, and if they are attempting a DDOS they won't be using any of your code to do it. How you prevent it is limiting how many times a single IP is allowed to send a request to your server within a given time span.

Comment: Which means you will need PHP to check the database for every request to make sure that the user isn't requesting too many times.

Comment: **One last tip:** If you are trying to prevent unwanted behavior from your users, before trying to come up your own solution google how the big sites are handling the problem. For example, Facebook and Google handle DDOS attacks every single day. They handle most of those attacks through DNS rules and a known attacker database.

Comment: thanks Nick, i got that, the question is what is the code on the PHP side that I use to trigger a client function, someone mentioned sockets. I guess the client needs to be running some kind of listener, then when it gets an update from the server it can run whatever code it wants, I am just not that familiar at all with sockets, and not even sure if the hosts I use will support them

Comment: there are other reasons I want to trigger code from the server, not just for DDOS reasons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143815/discussion-between-nick-j-and-user3005775).

Answer (score -3):

If you want to send something from server to client, try WebSockets.
Ratchet is php implementation of that. http://socketo.me/

You can write php script with ratchet and run it from command line (supervisor is recommended)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.